# How to import angular2 constant in a .scss file

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-cli

I have an *.scss* file where I have to write the path to the file using a **global variable** from another file. In this case, this variable should come from the environment folder which contains a

1. **environment.prod.ts** file for development server,
2. **environment.ts file** for local production

Basically, I have to use object properties from this folder/files.

The problem is, how would I import this files into my *.scss* file?

In typecript, it is easy:  `import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';`

I would like the string value from *scss* file

```
$path: '/subfolder/subfolder_second';
```

To swap using the variable from the environment file.

```
$path: environment.url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define two global scss file. one for production and one for dev.
Add Two configuration in .angular-cli.json (one for production mode and another one for dev mode).
Run command based on which mode you are in.

Comment: I have a .ts files where my variables are stored. I want to use this typescript file and give those variables from .ts to .scss